# How do I bind an optimize function output to a dataframe in R?

Tags: r, optimization, cbind

I am trying to take a function with 4 arguments(the first one is an unknown, and the last 3 are column arguments) and return the unknown argument (x) that produces the highest result. I want to cbind() this function result to the dataframe that contains the 3 aforementioned column arguments for every row in said dataframe.

The issue is, I can't get the optimize function to work properly. It tells me "object 'x' not found", but I don't see how you could use an optimize function in the first place if there isn't at least one unknown variable.

I've tried to construct a for loop as well as utilizing the plyr package to use the function ldply and loading the results into a different dataframe, but nothing has been fruitful thus far.

```
myfunction <- function(x, I, S, C) {
  (I + (x * S)) * (x - C)
  return(x)
}

results <- cbind(results,
                 y = optimize(
                   myfunction(x,
                              results$IN,
                              results$SL,
                              results$CO),
                   lower = 0,
                   upper = 100,
                   maximum = TRUE,
                   tol = .01
                 ))
```

The ideal end result is explained above, the new column containing that x value that gives the highest result for said function. Any help would be most appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Try `cbind(results, y = optimize(myfunction, etc)[[1]])`

Comment: @markus Unfortunately the same error occurs: object 'x' not found

Comment: @RuiBarradas Unfortunately the same error occurs: object 'x' not found

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(results)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(results, 20))`.